# xgboost with 3500 features

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm trying to make a solution for:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-financial-news/

This question relates to using only market price data to predict future prices (i.e. not news data, as specified in the kaggle problem).

I've used xgboost to determine that the most important factor for predicting the return is the recent return.

I've hypothesised that the prices of stocks may be related, so I have created a feature table with every stock's recent returns in it (including the target stock we want to predict). It's about 3500 columns wide.

When I train it, no matter what target stock I choose, the features it ranks as important are those near the left column of my features table - implying that stocks that begin with 'A' have special predictive power.

I expected that if I had picked Apple, I'd have gotten other tech companies' recent returns ranked as most important.

What can I try?

Comment: How big is your sample? The model is probably overfitting and modelling noise. You should reduce the number of features first. Finance in general is very hard to predict and model, so good luck with that if you are a newbie.

Comment: Reasonably small- 2498 trading days, 3780 stocks. I don't expect to win, I only hope to learn.

Comment: So your data is high-dimensional too (p>n), which is another problem. This requires in-depth analysis with advanced knowledge. Also, asking the same question on different sites is frowned upon.

Comment: What approach would you suggest I explore in this case? I considered trying to do a PCA, but I understood this wasn't necessary for xgb.

Comment: You should browse the site for similar problems to get a better look at the problems and possible solutions, there is no one way to do it.